# Why do the higher order derivatives of $\frac 1 x$ grow extremely large?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, intuition, curves

The $n$th derivative of $f(x) = \frac 1 x$ is $$f^{(n)}(x) = (-1)^n n! \frac 1 {x^{n+1}}$$ so that e.g. $$f^{(10)}(x) = \frac {10!} {x^{11}}.$$

While this formula is easy to calculate, it's somewhat mystifying.  Why do the higher derivatives grow so rapidly? Compare this with $g(x) = x^m$, where the higher derivatives quickly go to $0$.

Graphically, there's nothing I can see in the graph of $f$ to suggest these extremely large higher order derivatives.  After a certain point, the graph just seems flat (to within the limits of the eye's ability to recognize).

Intuitively, I'd associate such large derivative to some type of radical change or oscillation; but there's nothing I can see of the sort, only a pretty flat curve.

So: Why do the higher order derivatives of $\frac 1 x$ grow extremely large?

Comment: "After a certain point, the graph just seems flat". This part makes me think you are interested in the behaviour as $x \to \infty$, in which case the higher order derivatives get extremely _small_, not large. Did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: The question appears to be: For a fixed $a > 0$, why does the sequence of higher derivatives $\{f^{(n)}(a)\} = \{ (-1)^n \frac{n!}{a^{n+1}}\}$ at the point $a$ grow as rapidly as it does? I don't have an answer exactly, but want to point out that the sequence of _Taylor coefficients_ $\{ \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}\} = \{(-1)^n \frac{1}{a^{n+1}}\}$ decays (not grows).  Personally, I think the growth/decay of the Taylor coefficients is the more natural thing to look at.

Comment: I'll offer a "frame challenge", and suggest that after about the fifth or sixth derivative, nobody has a good intuitive sense what they represent, and our eyes certainly can't notice them on a graph.